# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in next.js

Tags: next.js, next.js13

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') at writeConfigurationDefaults (/home/anonymous/ProjectName/node_modules/next/dist/lib/typescript/writeConfigurationDefaults.js:223:30) at async verifyTypeScriptSetup (/home/anonymous/ProjectName/node_modules/next/dist/lib/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:120:9) at async DevServer.verifyTypeScript (/home/anonymous/ProjectName/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:648:34) at async DevServer.prepareImpl (/home/anonymous/ProjectName/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:672:9) at async NextServer.prepare (/home/anonymous/ProjectName/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:157:13) at async Server.<anonymous> (/home/anonymous/ProjectName/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/render-server.js:121:17) { type: 'TypeError' }`

1. update your next.js app to **13.4.1**
2. `npm run dev` or `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
0. You probably don't have an `include` directive in you config.

1. Back up your `tsconfig.json`
2. add an empty `"include": []` directive to your `tsconfig.json` file, and run dev. Next hijacks your file and adds some of its own types to your config.

I found this issue as well today. It seems not having an `include` directive in your child `tsconfig.json` file causes this error, which seems like a bug. The logic in `writeConfigurationDefaults` assumes an `include` key on the config object exists. What is strange is that the base config does have an include directive but this part of the code for whatever reason has not picked it up so the error occurs.